# How to add calculated values into column

Tags: sql

I'm trying to insert `ended_at - started_at` as a duration into the `duration_seconds` column. How do I do that?

[image]

Comment: Please post data here as text instead of an external link to an image.  Also, sql, is not a concrete database, tag it with the whatever dbms you are using.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run an SQL `UPDATE` statement to update value of `duration_seconds`
Something like this:

```
UPDATE all_trip
SET duration_seconds = DATETIME_DIFF(started_at, ended_at, SECOND)
-- safe check to only updating the record that is not calculated
WHERE duration_seconds IS NULL;
```

I use [DATETIME_DIFF function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions#datetime_diff), assuming that you're using Google Big Query (observed from your captured screenshot).

Answer (score -1):

Use this query:

```
SELECT t.started_at , t.ended_at , t.ended_at - t.started_at AS duration_seconds 
FROM   tableName as t
```